# Sum of fractions with square roots inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

What is the greatest integer $n$ such that

$n \leq 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2014}}$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator? I assuming you are not able to.

Comment: No calculator allowed.

Comment: Is this an ongoing contest? Do you have any ideas yourself?

Comment: The contest is over. When I did this I used approximation to get a sum a bit greater than the actual value (first answer), then approximated how much to take off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For positive integer $k$, we have $$2\sqrt{k} < \sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k} < 2\sqrt{k+1}$$
Taking reciprocals and rationalising the middle term, we get
$$\frac1{2\sqrt{k+1}}< \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k < \frac1{2\sqrt k}$$

The middle term telescopes and hence sums easily.  Thus we can have tight bounds on both sides:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac1{\sqrt{k}} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{2013}\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}} < 1+2\sum_{k=1}^{2013} (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})= 2\sqrt{2014}-1 \approx 88.75$$ and

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2014} \frac1{\sqrt k} > 1+\frac1{\sqrt2}+2\sum_{k=3}^{2014}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) = 2\sqrt{2015} - 2\sqrt3+1+\frac1{\sqrt2} \approx 88.02 $$

so you have your integer.

Answer (score 3):

We can view this as Riemann sum and compare with the integral (note that $x\mapsto\frac1{\sqrt x}$ is decreasing):
$$ 1+\int_1^{2014}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}>\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac1{\sqrt k}>\int_1^{2015}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}$$
i.e. 
$$ 88.76\approx2\sqrt{2014}-1>\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac1{\sqrt k}>2\sqrt{2015}-2\approx 87.8$$
Unfortunately, this is not enough to settle the question. But the lower bound can be improved to 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac1{\sqrt k}>1+\frac1{\sqrt2}+\int_3^{2015}\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}=1+\frac1{\sqrt2}+2(\sqrt{2015}-\sqrt 3)\approx 88.02$$
(I leave it to you if you compute $\sqrt{2015}$ etc. to sufficient precision or extract a few more of the initial summands; )

Answer (score 0):

The integral criterium (see the last step of the proof of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) gives you some great upper and lower bounds:
$$\int_N^{M+1}f(x)\,dx\le\sum_{n=N}^Mf(n)\le f(N)+\int_N^M f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Yeah, the series is divergent. Are you sure this gives sufficient bounds?

Comment: I've edited the upper bound since we are only asked to sum up to $2014$...

Comment: But it didn't make sense with $\infty$ as it diverges. I was just wondering if you know this leads to success since I'm too lazy to work out the details :)

Comment: it does indeed. And in an incredibly good way :D

Answer (score 0):

By using induction it's easy to see that
$$
2\sqrt{n+1}\lt2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\le2\sqrt{n}+1
$$